# Optimized way to search an object array based on multiple key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, optimization, data-structures

I wrote a generic extension method which will return an item which matches all the given search criterion (lookUpArray). Here is the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/qutiwoxaxe/edit?js,console).

```
/***************************Extension Method****************************/

    var utils = {};
            // Could create a utility function to do this
            utils.searchInArray = function (lookUpArray, caseSensitiveSearch) {
                if (!lookUpArray || lookUpArray.length <= 0)
                    return null;

                caseSensitiveSearch = caseSensitiveSearch || false;
                var self = this;
                var item = null;
                for (var index = 0; index < self.length; index++) {
                    item = self[index];
                    var exist = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
                        if (item[lookUpArray[i].key] === lookUpArray[i].value) {
                            exist = exist * true;
                        } else { exist = exist * false; }
                    }
                    if (exist)
                        return item;
                };
                return exist ? item : null;
            };

            // or we could create a function on the Array prototype indirectly
            Array.prototype.excSearchObjArrayForKeyValue = utils.searchInArray;



/***************************Extension Method****************************/


        var inputObjectArray= [
            { emailType: 'primary', id: 1, username: 'saurabh', email: 'test@gmail.com', phone: '123' },
            { emailType: 'additional', id: 2, email: 'test2@gmail.com' },
            { emailType: 'additional', id: 2, email: 'test2@gmail.com', username:'spp' }
        ];

        //Below is the search criterion array. Extension method should return only that object which 
        //matches complete below lookUpArray
        var lookUpArray = [{ key: 'emailType', value: 'additional' }, { key: 'id', value: 2 }];

        var result = inputObjectArray.excSearchObjArrayForKeyValue(lookUpArray);
        console.log(result);
```

Is there any possibility to optimize (performance) above searching?

Comment: The inner loop's `else` case could have a `break`, or a `continue outer` if you add an `outer:` label to the outer loop. Also, the inner loop's `if` case is redundant, it won't change the value of `exist` (except the first time when it changes `true` to `1`).

Comment: Since you want to improve the perfs, store the lengths, rather than retrieve the on each iteration ;)

Comment: Why do you want to optimize performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your use case. If you will be running the search function fairly often (compared to how often the array is modified), and if you have a limited number of possible keys to search across, you might find it worthwhile to create and maintain an index-like structure. Right now your lookup is an `O(m*n)` operation, where `m` is the number of keys and `n` is the number of items in the array. With a proper data structure in place, the lookup could become an `O(m)` operation instead. Since I'm guessing `n` is likely to be the bigger number by far, this could make the search scale far more efficiently.

If it doesn't make sense to do that, then you should at least short-circuit your inner loop.

```
            var self = this;
            for (var index = 0; index < self.length; index++) {
                var item = self[index];
                var matches = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
                    var lookUpItem = lookUpArray[i];
                    if (item[lookUpItem.key] !== lookUpItem.value) {
                        matches = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(matches) {
                    return item;
                }
            };
            return null;
```

Or, as nnnnnn suggests, you could accomplish the same thing more concisely with a label:

```
            var self = this;
            outer:
            for (var index = 0; index < self.length; index++) {
                var item = self[index];
                for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
                    var lookUpItem = lookUpArray[i];
                    if (item[lookUpItem.key] !== lookUpItem.value) {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
                return item;
            };
            return null;
```

If you're using ES6, you could even leverage the `.find()` and `.every()` functions.

```
            var self = this;
            return self.find(item => 
                lookUpArray.every(lookUpItem => 
                    item[lookUpItem.key] === lookUpItem.val));
```

And I would advise against adding this method to the Array prototype. I'd just make it a utility method.

Comment: The `.some()` *function* would slow things down wouldn't it? (Compared to a `for` loop.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: It's likely that it would be slightly slower, but it's hard to say, without a benchmark. If it's natively supported by the browser environment (as opposed to being a polyfill), I could envision it being slightly faster. Either way, I usually find it best to focus on large-scale efficiency and readability, and only make nitty-gritty optimizations when absolutely necessary.

Comment: That inner loop short-circuit changes the result. It should be `if (... != ...) break` (and still using the `exist` variable or some equivalent), because the goal is to find an item that matches all of the lookup criteria.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Good catch! I think I fixed it. How does it look now?

Comment: Yep, I think that's the right logic now. (If it were my code I'd probably use `continue` together with a label on the outer loop, thus avoiding the need for a `matches` variable, but either way drops out of the inner loop at the earliest possible moment.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, I added that one in just for good measure. Feel free to correct my code if I did it wrong. In all my years of Javascript programming, I'd never even known that existed until you mentioned it.

Comment: *"Feel free to correct my code"* - Done. (Colon after the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), and it would need to be before the `for` not inside it. Some people write it on the same line like `outer: for(...)`.) I don't use labels often, but occasionally they're helpful with nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize array functions like `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.every` instead of iterating through items yourself:

```
var utils = {
  searchInArray: function(targetArray, lookupArray, caseSensitiveSearch) {
    return targetArray.filter(function(x) {
      return lookupArray.every(function(lookup) {
        if (x[lookup.key] === undefined)
          throw new Error('No ' + lookup.key + ' property in object ' + x);

        if (typeof x[lookup.key] !== typeof lookup.value)
          throw new Error('Type mismatch on property ' + lookup.key ' + in object ' + x);

        if (typeof lookup.value === 'string' && caseSensitiveSearch)
          return x[lookup.key].toLowerCase() === lookup.value.toLowerCase();
        else
          return x[lookup.key] === lookup.value;
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Working demo snippet:

```js
var utils = {
  searchInArray: function(targetArray, lookupArray, caseSensitiveSearch) {
    return targetArray.filter(function(x) {
      return lookupArray.every(function(lookup) {
        if (x[lookup.key] === undefined)
          throw new Error('No ' + lookup.key + ' property in object ' + x);

        if (typeof x[lookup.key] !== typeof lookup.value)
          throw new Error('Type mismatch on property ' + lookup.key ' + in object ' + x);

        if (typeof lookup.value === 'string' && caseSensitiveSearch)
          return x[lookup.key].toLowerCase() === lookup.value.toLowerCase();
        else
          return x[lookup.key] === lookup.value;
      });
    });
  }
};

var inputObjectArray = [
  { emailType: 'primary', id: 1, username: 'saurabh', email: 'test@gmail.com', phone: '123' }, 
  { emailType: 'additional', id: 2, email: 'test2@gmail.com' }, 
  { emailType: 'additional', id: 2, email: 'test2@gmail.com', username: 'spp' }
];

var lookUpArray = [{
  key: 'emailType',
  value: 'aDdItIoNaL'
}, {
  key: 'id',
  value: 2
}];

var result = utils.searchInArray(inputObjectArray, lookUpArray, true);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This makes the code much neater, but is it an "optimisation"? Wouldn't using those array methods with callbacks be slower than `for` loops?

Comment: @nnnnnn to be fair OP did not mention what exactly they want optimise. This answer optimises the structure (and readability) ;-P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Arrays.find` function.

The find() method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array 
satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Have a look at this examples:

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

You can also write your custom logic, for eg. to find prime numbers:

```
function isPrime(element, index, array) {
  var start = 2;
  while (start <= Math.sqrt(element)) {
    if (element % start++ < 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return element > 1;
}

console.log([4, 6, 8, 12].find(isPrime)); // undefined, not found
console.log([4, 5, 8, 12].find(isPrime)); // 5
```

Pls mark correct if helpful.

Comment: The question is explictly about a generic method that covers matches on multiple properties in an array of objects.

Comment: besides not actually solving the problem, it's unclear how this is supposed to represent a performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

To  get first matching obj you  can try this

```
utils.searchInArray = function(lookUpArray, caseSensitiveSearch) {
    if (!lookUpArray || lookUpArray.length <= 0)
      return null;
    caseSensitiveSearch = caseSensitiveSearch || true;
    var self = this;
    return self.find(function(obj) {
      return lookUpArray.every(function(lookup) {
        if (typeof lookup.value === 'string' && caseSensitiveSearch)
          return obj[lookup.key].toLowerCase() === lookup.value.toLowerCase();
        else
          return obj[lookup.key] === lookup.value;
      });

    });
  };
```

To get the all matching object

```
utils.searchInArray = function(lookUpArray, caseSensitiveSearch) {
    if (!lookUpArray || lookUpArray.length <= 0)
      return null;
    caseSensitiveSearch = caseSensitiveSearch || true;
    var self = this;
    return self.filter(function(obj) {
      return lookUpArray.every(function(lookup) {
        if (typeof lookup.value === 'string' && caseSensitiveSearch)
          return obj[lookup.key].toLowerCase() === lookup.value.toLowerCase();
        else
          return obj[lookup.key] === lookup.value;
      });

    });
  };
```